# Jquery on keypress

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm looking for a function that gives an alert when a certain character key (g) is pressed in the first position of a postal code, and then disables the submit button if the postal code has a letter G in the beginning.
Is this possible?

My current code to detect a key up on the postal code field at the moment is this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var someTextInputField = "#postal-code";
  
  $(someTextInputField).on("keyup", function() {
    alert('not a valid postal code');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="postal-code" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Javascript without extra libraries

```js
document.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
  if (e.target.id === "postal-code") {
    var disable = /^g/i.test(e.target.value),
      submit = document.getElementById("submit");
    
    if (disable && !submit.disabled) {
      alert("You cannot start a postal code with a G");
    }
    
    submit.disabled = disable;
  }
});
```

```html
<input placeholder="Address" />
<input id="postal-code" placeholder="Postal Code" />
<button id="submit">Submit</button>
```

## jQuery

```js
$(document).on("input", "#postal-code", function (e) {
  var disable = /^g/i.test(this.value),
      $submit = $("#submit");
    
    if (disable && !$submit.prop("disabled")) {
      alert("You cannot start a postal code with a G");
    }
    
    $submit.prop("disabled", disable);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input placeholder="Address" />
<input id="postal-code" placeholder="Postal Code" />
<button id="submit">Submit</button>
```

Comment: This works but how do i get an alert to pop up using this function?

Comment: Also this doesn't function if you add an elment id to the event listener?

Comment: @SaoTith, in the event listener, I'm using `input` instead of `keyup` because it is more responsive. `keyup` only gets triggered when you let go of the key, but `input` gets triggered after each character is entered (so if you hold down "j" until you get "jjjjj" then you will have five events. To check the id you need to look at `e.target`, which is the actual input box. I'll modify the answer to show this.

Comment: also how would this function if you were to use multiple letters, say G, H, I?

Comment: Might help to [read more about regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions). You could just replace `/^g/` with `/^[ghi]/i`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `this.value[0]` to get the first character of the input. Then test whether it's one of the allowed characters.

```js
$("#input").on("keyup", function() {
  if (this.value != '') {
    var firstchar = this.value[0].toUpperCase();
    if (firstchar != 'A' && firstchar != 'G') {
      alert('not a valid postal code');
      $("#submitID").prop("disabled", true);
    } else {
      $("#submitID").prop("disabled", false);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="input"/>
```

Comment: I read the question as needing to disable a submit button if the input starts with a "g".

Comment: I read it as asking how to detect what the input starts with. As in the question, alert is just some example code that gets run when it's the case, he'll replace that with the real code.

Comment: What needs to happen is the submit button needs to be disabled when the first input character of the postal code field is G or g and automatically alerts that it is not a valid postale code and erases the input . thanks for your responses though

Comment: OK, I've added the code to disable and enable the submit button. It seems like that should be pretty obvious, though.

Answer (score 0):

Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/oyc2L9sy/12/

html:

```
<input id="test" type="text" />
```

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#test").on("keypress", function(e) {  
        if ((e.keyCode == '65') ||
            (e.keyCode == '71')) { 
            alert('not a valid postal code');
            return false;
        }
    });  
});
```

Comment: This would also disable any time g or G is typed I need only to detect on the first position (first letter of the postal code)